# Opencart 2.2.0.0: You don't have permission to access API

Tags: php, api, permissions, opencart

I'm using Apache:2.4.7; PHP: 5.4.24; Opencart: 2.2.0.0; 
I've created the API with the name => REST and generated a API key.

[IMAGE API page of admin opencart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riZ5l.png)

I do the login in this API this way:

```
$url = "http://localhost/upload/index.php?route=api/login";
$params = array('key=dpUFrufwZdbctqKaFckZz7WudebaAQO7orP6Y3QtpxTsbOyjNjpQZgIgAtp4SQVJWSfvpj2Acpis0E382EO3PhRcSMSJ6MpjV8EDXlWAtEC7aD3aGUou2yCL7ETpDARiIpzgy7auG2hhllIRjeUtXsiVUu6ENlJ7fBtIKvomjpTeaMXpIVklWx5CyxwIIGUA5CoYLGD4qPFvr6OAqDxJvhktMOjhj4DlKTvkTp0WzuoRBfRCDt8N4XIHMxbTIH1u'
    );

$parameters = implode('&', $params);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);

//execute post
set_time_limit(120);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

It ruturns me a TOKEN, so I can use this token to access others link in this REST. But, when I use the TOKEN like this:

```
$url = "http://localhost/upload/index.php?route=api/cart/products";
$params = array('token=bxXXgBX3NAue7dDnTC7pzQxf2qLZX8fB',
    );

$parameters = implode('&', $params);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);

//execute post
set_time_limit(120);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

print_r($result);
```

It returns me a error like:

`{"error": {"warning":"warning: you don't have permission to access API!"}}`

Could anybody help me?

What I've already tried:

```
- Permission for all user (user group)
- Pay atention to domain and sub domain
- Recreate the API and regenerate the API Key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding your IP address into the allowed IP address section in the Opencart Admin?